# How do I fix "ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar"

Tags: python, csv, jupyter-notebook, screen-scraping

[picture of the code causing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKzes.png)
I created a nba player stat projection model a couple years ago and wanted to update for the last couple seasons. I created a new csv file with the more recent nba player stats but I get this error using the new csv file even though the formatting is the exact same. Anyone know how I can fix this?

I tried to do scrape the data again created another csv file but I had the same result

Comment: See what you get without `.item()` ... maybe it is more than one?

Comment: @topsail It's just empty when I remove .item(). I really think it has something to do with the csv file cause I don't have an error when I use the old one on the exact same code.

Comment: Can you post the error message again? I think I remember the stack tracing checking if `something == 1` ... maybe an empty result is an error here (and you said it is just empty ... so ...)

Comment: Yes, the length must be 1, or item() throws an error - so not about the format of the data, it is about the data itself.

Comment: @topsail Okay thanks i'll take a look at the data in the files and see if I find any discrepancies

Comment: I'm guessing the current_player_id is not present in the current_player_season

Comment: Please post code as code, not image. The problem has to be reproducible.